# Is it possible to install older wine releases?

Tags: wine

One application I used to use with wine stopped working. I suspect something in wine has changed and so the application no longer works. Is it possibel to install earlier versions of wine in Ubuntu? Are there some repositories, or would I have t ocompile by hand?

Comment: You can use either PlayOnLinux which allows you to make "profiles" for your applications to use a specific wine version or you can get the Wine source and compile it as you say to have different versions installed.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is. PlayOnLinux works for me, thanks Uri!